# Why droid explorer show different set of folders than the one on file explorer?

Tags: droid-explorer

This is what droid explorer shows

[image]

This is in file explorer

[image]

According to file explorer I am at the root. So How can I see what's on file explorer via droidexplorer or via versa?

Answer (score 1):

The former shows the ***root file system*** – the latter what MTP provides (usually the internal or external SD card). Different directories/places, hence of course it shows different sets of folders :)

Comment: According to file explorer I am at the root. So How can I see what's on file explorer via droidexplorer or via versa?

Comment: According to file explorer your at the root *of that storage* – not necessarily at the root of the entire file system on your device. MTP doesn't serve the entire file system, but "shared storage" (internal/external SD card) only, which is why, if you have both internal *and* external SD, you'll usually find 2 entries for your device.